# How to select event automatically while loading events? Like moveTo(date:), moveTo(event:) functionality available?

Tags: ios, swift, calendarkit

I am using this https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit library in my project. I just want to clarify one doubt which is required for my project implementation.

Currently I am using this library in my project to load the calendar events. But now I am having requirement like, I need to load the events on particular date and move/select to the particular event automatically while loading the events.

I can use moveTo(date:) method to open particular date. But I need to select event automatically.

So, People who used calendar kit already, please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this functionality is currently not supported and requires changes in the library.

You'll need to either modify the library and submit a pull request for it, or fork and modify the library yourself.